# How to Delete Partitions

Tags: partition

I recently purchased a used 2017 iMac 27". It has a 2TB HD and the guy who previously owned ran Windows on Bootcamp. I tried to use the Disk Utility app to merge the partitions but no luck. I keep getting an error message saying there is corruption. I would like to have all 2TB for my MacOS. Not being familiar with terminal, I don't want to erase anything important.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Myself and many others would recommend that, because you acquired the device from someone else, you should wipe the drive and reinstall macOS anyway to ensure no malware is present. Of course, back up any important data first.

Comment: Agreed. Nothing on that Mac currently belongs to you, not even the OS itself. There will come a point some time down the road, when the old user's AppleID & password is required to perform some task… & you won't know it.

Comment: The original owner wiped it clean. When I booted it for the first time, it was like it was brand new.How can I install a fresh copy of the operating system? All of my file are on one drive, and I would like to do this now before I do accumulate any documents on the HD.

Comment: Also, will wiping the drive delete the partitions?

Comment: I tried to wipe the HD & reinstall macOS. Had issues with the install. However, I was able to get the iMac up and running again. But I still have 620Gb as untitled & 511GB free space. After the new install of macOS, I am still not able to merge the partitions. The - is greyed out on the 620gb and when I try to merge the 511GB, I get an error message. the error message is "Operation failed because corruption was found in the container disk2 of one of its volume". I tried to run the first aid but no luck. All I want to do is have the 2TB the I can use and not partitioned.